# I want to parametrize the values in one field in my robot script, i am trying to use List variable but not getting the output. please suggest

Tags: robotframework

In my test in Robot framework i need to parameterizeone value, that i need to put to one field in my web application.I am trying to use list variable but it is not giving the output.

i have used it like below

@{Changed_Customers}        14907400    14919957    14276033

here the first value RF is saying wrong keyword where as i m putting this as the value to the list variable.

Kindly suggest.

Also if there is some alternative to parameterize and use each value one by one kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a list inside a test case is done via the create list keyword

`*** Test Cases ***
A Sample 
  @{Changed_Customers}  Create List  14907400  14919957  14276033`

See also the documentation for [create list](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.4#Create%20List) in the builtin test library documentation.